# Blender Extrusion doubles

Tags: extrude

If I extrude like i see in tutorials, it doubles the extrusion on the opposite side of the object. for example. Extrude a cube face and the face on the opposite side is extruded as well. New project, no mirror modification on as far as i know.

thank you in advance!

Comment: hello, maybe show some pictures or share your file?

Answer (score 2):

You likely have Tool -> Options -> Symmetry turned on (X being on but Y and Z not is actually default somewhere I think). In 2.90, this stuff is by default in the right-hand sidebar of the 3D View editor. Press N to show the sidebar, then click the Tool tab...